# Running out of memory when running `react-scripts build` on bitbucket pipeline

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket, create-react-app

Running out of memory when running `react-scripts build` on bitbucket pipeline even with size=2 and a 3070MBx2 memory allocated = that means a little over 6gb of memory and its still not enough to build the script.

### So far I've tried the following:

- added `max_old_space_size=6000` to build script (`react-scripts --max_old_space_size=6000 build`)
- adding `"resolutions": { "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0"}` to my package.json(https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10119#issuecomment-734184155)
- added  `"devDependencies": { "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",`  to my package.json(https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8096#issuecomment-571717268)

So far the only thing that worked was either removing big packages or adding: `cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to my run script. which is not ideal because I want source maps.

### Logs from bitbucket

```
> react-scripts --max_old_space_size=6000 build
Creating an optimized production build...
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xxxxxx0.1.0 build: `react-scripts --max_old_space_size=6000 build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xxxxxx0.1.0 @0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-08T17_05_53_040Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
2021-07-08T17:05:53.326849634Z stdout P
```

Comment: can you share the bitbucket build log?

Comment: Added the only relevant logs i can think off.